# Are there any command line syslog listeners for Linux?

Tags: linux, syslog

We have several embedded systems that can be configured to send log data to a remote server for debugging purposes. However such is the hassle of configuring the developers machine to listen and filter this data most of the guys tend to just watch the syslog traffic with something like Wireshark. Are there any command line syslog tools that can be configured to listen to a temporary port use in these debugging scenarios? I've had a bit of a search on-line but haven't been able to turn anything up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want something quick and dirty, just use netcat to listen on the syslog port. Redirecting to a file, filtering what you see, etc. can all be done with tee or shell redirection, grep, awk, etc.

```
sudo nc -l 514
```

Add the `-u` flag if using a UDP transport.

Comment: can you explain how this works? does syslog publish to anything connected to this port? is that how it works?